"This kind of expression is always falsy" error in angular template
I've updated my dependencies lately and I now have the error "this kind of expression is always falsy" when I use the ?. operator in HTML templates. For example:
<app-configuration-panel [configuration]="currentApp?.configuration" />

This code works and compiles, my editor is the only one complaining about the syntax.
Quick note: I use Sublime Text with LSP (eslint/angular), if I open my project with VS Code I don't have any error. My guess is that VSCode might use a different Typescript version than the one configured in my package.json. I'm currently using TS 5.5.4 and Angular 18.2.8
Is there a way to ignore this specific error? I still want to have the other errors/warnings in my templates and so far I've only seen solutions that turn off the whole thing.
Edit: I forced VSCode to use my project's TS version and still don't see the error. I guess it's a difference of implementation between the Angular/ESLint plugins then, with ST's plugins being more strict than VSCode's.

I think it's due to TS version: seems that TS 5.6.0 (and possible some earlier versions) is returning such errors, but TS 5.5.4 is not.

So I (wrongly) notified the issue to the ngx-html-syntax's author on GitHub and even though it has nothing to do with their plugin, they gave me this solution:

Looks like it's because LSP-angular upgraded to ts 5.6 too soon. The
fix is easy, though. Simply install @angular/language-server and
typescript@5.5.4 somewhere (in my case at ~/tmp/angular-ls/) and point
LSP-angular to use that.
An example for Windows users, *nix users can simply replace the path
with *nix format
(see code below)
LSP-angular also has an example at the bottom of its readme for projects that have language server package as part of
its dependencies, that would work on any platform.

The configuration that should be added to LSP-angular's custom settings:
{
  "command": [
    "${node_bin}", "C:\\Users\\chenp\\tmp\\angular-ls\\node_modules\\@angular\\language-server\\index.js",
    "--logFile", "C:\\Users\\chenp\\tmp\\angular-ls\\ngls.log",
    "--ngProbeLocations", "C:\\Users\\chenp\\tmp\\angular-ls\\node_modules",
    "--tsProbeLocations", "C:\\Users\\chenp\\tmp\\angular-ls\\node_modules",
    "--stdio"
  ],
}


Assuming that if there is no currentApp you do not want to display the configuration panel you can edit your template this way to make it more robust:
@if(currentApp){
  <app-configuration-panel [configuration]="currentApp.configuration" />
}


Using this approach guarantees that your configuration @Input never receives null or undefined, and also conveniently avoids the TS warning.

Thanks but this is just a sample to illustrate what's causing the error, the component takes other props and null/undefined is a valid input that I expect for this particular input.

Another approach ;) => @if(currentApp?.configuration; as config) { <app-configuration-panel [configuration]="config"> }

@AlpineA110R Besides the fact that it still hides the component (not what I want), this would give me the exact same error as the ?. syntax within HTML is what triggers the error. The suggested answer is cleaner in my opinion, it's just not what I want (it's a workaround and not an actual fix)
